# change text color by clicking?

Tags: java, android

I want T mae my text color changes by click e.g. (becomes white)

I defined text view and made a click listener

what to write in click listener ??

```
public OnClickListener TextListener = new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

// what to put here ?

        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do:

```
textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: @mohamedrashad Congrats, and please don't forget to select as answer if its solved your problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

v is the current view in your case your textview. Each textview which this listener will have white background.

```
v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) v;
textView.setTextColor(yourColor);
```

Remember to set also your text view as clickable by calling `setClickable(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

If we need to implement ActionUp ,DOWN and others you can simply make a listener for text color change.

```
public class TextTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {     
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ((TextView)view).setTextColor(0xFFFFFFFF); //white color
                break;          
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ((TextView)view).setTextColor(0xFF000000); //black color
                break;
    } 
        return false;   
    } 
}
```

Dont forget to make it clickable

```
YourTextView.setOnTouchListener(new TextTouchListener());
```

Happy Coding